# Facebook login button rendering incorrectly

Tags: html, facebook

I am using the following to add a login with facebook button on my website:

```
<div class="fb-login-button" data-show-faces="false" data-width="100"
    data-max-rows="2" data-size="large" data-scope="xxx">Start Here</div>
```

This works fine in IE9, but it doesn't work in Safari/Chrome.  Instead I get the following button:

[image: Wrong facebook button]

Notice how the facebook logo is missing?  That's because in webkit the following line is generated by facebook:

```
<i class="pluginFaviconButtonIcon img sp_login-button sx_login-button_"></i>
```

The part that's wrong is "sx_login-button_"  that's missing the size specifier, which in this case is "large".  In IE9, this is "sx_login-button_large" instead, which works.

Any ideas as why this is not working webkit?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I am having the same problem and was having a hard time finding the root cause in the CSS. You nailed that part, but I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: I wish I had good new, but I don't.  I suspect it has to do with the fb settings for the app, but I haven't nailed it down yet.  Please let me know if you ever find a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've figured it out.  I have the plugin Ghostery installed which was blocking Facebook activity.  I know, pretty stupid but I was just looking at the layout at the time :).  but that's why things were getting messed up for me.  Check to make sure you don't have blockers running.